# When I use GNU nm it doesn't display __DTOR_LIST__

Tags: c, linux, destructor, nm

I have a "big" problem.
I  am currently trying to get the address of my dtor list in a program on Linux (it's a virtual machine). Obviously there is a destructor function but when I use nm and all the addresses and their names are shown I can't find it; the only thing that is related to it, is do_global_dtors_aux. Besides when the code is run it works perfectly fine as expected.
Here is my piece of code:

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  static void cleanup(void) __attribute__ ((destructor));

  int main() {
      printf("in the main function...");
      exit(0);
  }

  void cleanup(void){
      printf("in the cleanup");
  }
```

And here is when I use `nm`

```
0000000000600808 d _DYNAMIC
00000000006009f0 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000400678 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
00000000004007e0 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000600800 d __JCR_END__
0000000000600800 d __JCR_LIST__
0000000000600a38 D __TMC_END__
0000000000600a38 A __bss_start
0000000000600a28 D __data_start
0000000000400550 t __do_global_dtors_aux
00000000006007f0 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000600a30 D __dso_handle
00000000006007e8 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
                 w __gmon_start__
00000000006007f0 t __init_array_end
00000000006007e8 t __init_array_start
00000000004005d0 T __libc_csu_fini
00000000004005e0 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000600a38 A _edata
0000000000600a40 A _end
000000000040066c T _fini
0000000000400430 T _init
0000000000400490 T _start
00000000004004bc t call_gmon_start
00000000004005b4 t cleanup
0000000000600a38 b completed.6092
0000000000600a28 W data_start
00000000004004e0 t deregister_tm_clones
                 U exit@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000400570 t frame_dummy
000000000040059c T main
                 U printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000400510 t register_tm_clones
```

Comment: It's a good idea to include a newline at the end of the `printf()` format strings.  Or, for simple 'output a string' calls, use `puts()` instead.

Comment: I don't see in the documentation (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html) where it states that `__DTOR_LIST__` will be an actual symbol in the executable.

Comment: you might be able to use the 'atexit()' function, which is portable, as the '__attribute__ ((destructor));' is not portable.

Comment: I see but the problem here is to know where the .dtor is and apparently it has disappeared.... but thank you for the information next I will use atexit()

Answer (score 1):

It seems there have been some changes in gcc. ctor and dtor list have been replaced by init_array and fini_array.

I'm not exactly sure if that's what happened to you, but when i saw the diff of objdumps between (a program with destructor,constructor attribute declaration) and (a program without them), the mostly highlighted sections are .init_array and .fini_array

This may be refering to that
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46770

I'm not sure of how to get the adress of functions from the list but hopefully you can take it from here.

A simple example they(on gcc bugzilla) refered to which might help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void
init ()
{
  printf ("init_array\n");
}

static void (*const init_array []) ()
      __attribute__ ((section (".init_array"), aligned (sizeof (void *))))
        = { init };

static void
fini ()
{
  printf ("fini_array\n");
}

static void (*const fini_array []) ()
      __attribute__ ((section (".fini_array"), aligned (sizeof (void *))))
        = { fini };

static void
ctor ()
{
  printf ("ctor\n");
}

static void (*const ctors []) ()
      __attribute__ ((section (".ctors"), aligned (sizeof (void *))))
        = { ctor };

static void
dtor ()
{
  printf ("dtor\n");
}

static void (*const dtors []) ()
      __attribute__ ((section (".dtors"), aligned (sizeof (void *))))
        = { dtor };

int
main ()
{
  printf ("main\n");
}
```